# Why is the Selenium driver.find command returning a list twice as large as it should be?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium to do some web scraping of urls. However, I've noticed that Python is inserting blanks in between urls.

**This is being returned to me:**

> ['uk.linkedin.com › pauljgarner',
>
> '',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › namakarskiy',
>
> '',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › danny-butler-62834777',
>
> '',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › ksrameshkanth'

**When it should be:**

> ['uk.linkedin.com › pauljgarner',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › namakarskiy',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › danny-butler-62834777',
>
> 'uk.linkedin.com › ksrameshkanth'

**My Relevant Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/yu/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https:www.google.com')

##inputting google search##
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_query.send_keys(parameters.search_query)
search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

##compiling list of linkedin urls##
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
linkedin_urls = [url.text for url in linkedin_urls]

linkedin_urls
len(linkedin_urls)
##the above command returns length of 20, when it should be 10##
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Haven't seen anything similar on the web

Comment: Are you at liberty to say what the search query is? Because perhaps iuh30 matches more elements than you think.

Comment: If you want to remove them try `linkedin_urls = list(filter(None, linkedin_urls))` at the end

Comment: use `if` in list comprehension `[url.text for url in linkedin_urls if url.text]`

Comment: The solution by CC7052 worked, but I wasn't able to make the code provided by furas  work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and I get as many spaces as the data elements (exactly as you've indicated). When I looked at the elements at the webpage, I found that elements are duplicated when you use the class `iUh30`.

I fixed the issue by searching for a parent `div` element that has the class `TbwUpd NJjxre` (using an XPath query), as follows:

**Instead of:**

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
```

**Use this:**

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='TbwUpd NJjxre']")
```

Hope it helps.